# Как избежать дубликации функции и вынести в отдельное место?

Tags: angular

В каждом компоненте, где нужно диалоговое окно, имеется функция:

```
private get dialogConfig(): MatDialogConfig {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.width = '900px';
    dialogConfig.height = '750px';
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    return dialogConfig;
}
```

Этот участок кода дублируется в компонентах. Хочу его вынести и переиспользовать. Как это лучше сделать?

В голову приходит вынести его как есть с дщобавлением `export`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать сервис, внутри которого будет этот метод.
Так в дальнейшем будет проще его "замещать" другой реализацией.

Кроме того, если вам внутри метода понадобится ссылка на зависимость внутри Angular сервис сможет ее получить, функция через export - нет.

Comment: Можно пример для оего случая? Нужна ли такая сильная абстракция?

Comment: @Jony, дописал не много ответ.